# Pipe is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-stream

I have a function that returns a stream and I want to pipe that value to another function then return it in an Express response like so:

```
const { Duplex } = require('stream');
const request = require('request');

const example = async function getRequest() {
  return request({ blah }).pipe(Duplex);
};

const secondExample = async function getRequestSecond() {
  return example().pipe(Duplex);
};

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  return secondExample().pipe(res);
});
```

These functions all sit in different classes, but the general idea is the same. My understanding of Streams leads me to believe that piping the data to a Duplex stream and returning that should allow me to pipe it all the way down to the response, but at the `secondExmaple` function and in the `router.get` function I start to get `TypeError: secondExample(...).pipe is not a function` and I'm not understanding why.

Comment: Why did you mark those functions with `async`? This makes a function to always return a Promise which has no `pipe` method.

Comment: Because in my actual application those functions do perform some asynchronous stuff that has to be awaited. I was awaiting the functions but my linter yelled at me for awaiting in a return statement. The ```request``` function should be awaited either way.

Comment: if you use Promises, use `.then` to access the resolved value

Comment: But I can also await them, which will allow me to access the resolved value, correct? Even with the resolved value accessed by awaiting I get that error.

Comment: You can't await streams. Only thenable objects. And if you have async function that resolves with a stream you need to use await before calling `pipe` on it `(await secondExample()).pipe(res)`

Comment: So, for example, if I was using the request-promise library I would ```return (await request({})).pipe(Duplex);```. Then I'd await that function in the same manner and so on and so on. When I do that I get another error ```TypeError: (intermediate value).pipe is not a function```.

Comment: this.usersForm
      .get('userInput')
      .valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        this.isLoading = true;
        if (value !== "") {
          console.log(value)
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      });            the loader does not work may be because observable wait for a keyup event to finish ?